# Magento custom payment method module development

Tags: php, magento-1.7

Is there a comprehensive tutorial related to the development of custom payment extension for magento 1.7. I found these article but they are old and I have the same code already in amazon checkout extension. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

I started modifying an amazon checkout payment module which we are using in the old version of Magento. Now we have upagraded from 1.4 to 1.7 and the amazon module is not working. I have modified the code as in the googlecheckout module. Specially I modified the order saving and the order confirming functions. The module is now working but have a lot of issues, because many things are different that the googlecheckout module and also there callback response is different.

Also I have searched the amazon checkout extension for 1.7 but the one I found is not for US. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/amazon-checkout-extension-9731.html.

Comment: For creating an order I found that the best thing to do is to load an existing order, and then modify it. Not extremely efficient, but gets the job done. Can't you try to install the europe version and modify it for US ?

Comment: Yes I know the way to place order is to first make a quote and when return in the notify function we have to convert it to the order, plus other things. I also tried to modify that module but that requires more time to completely understand that process. I want to understand the flow of the payment and also the sample code, So I can modify for amazon payments.